# Heap sort Algorithms issue

Tags: python, algorithm

I followed the clrs book for algo. 
I'm trying make heapsort in python. But It give me the error that r falls out side of the index but I don't know why.

```
def Max_Heapify(A,i,size_of_array):
    l = 2*i
    r = l + 1
    if l <= size_of_array and A[l] > A[i]:
        largest = l
    else:
        largest = i
    if r <= size_of_array and A[r] > A[largest]:
        largest = r
    if i != largest:
        A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
        Max_Heapify(A,largest,size_of_array)

def Build_Max_Heap(A,size_of_array):
    for i in range((math.floor(size_of_array/2)) - 1 , 0 ,-1):
        Max_Heapify(A,i,size_of_array)

def Heapsort(A,size_of_array):
    Build_Max_Heap(A,size_of_array)
    for i in range(size_of_array - 1 ,0 ,-1):
        A[0],A[i] = A[i],A[0]
        size_of_array = size_of_array - 1
        Max_Heapify(A,0,size_of_array)
```

Comment: All of your indentation in the functions is off. Please fix it and paste the full traceback.

Comment: Sry  When I posted it the indentations got mess up

Answer (score 1):

In most of the programming languages, the size of the array is bigger than the last index. For example, the following array: `A = [1, 2, 3]`, its size is 3, but the index of the last element is 2  (`A[3]` should return that it is out of index). You are verifying if r is less **or equal** to the array size, so when it is equal, it is bigger than the last index. Your verification should be:

`if r < size_of_array`

Comment: if r < size_of_array and A[r] > A[largest]:
IndexError: list index out of range

So I did that. When I take the array that i'm using 
it should something like 
array_1 = array_1 - 1.